# counting for random consecutive sequence of data and zeros in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have consecutive data in a column which has data and zeros recurring as per below but in no particular pattern.
i want to be able to count the data items and zeros as a subtotal and to be able to sum the data items as a subtotal. i have done the calc manually but want to automate with just one formula in EXCEL. can u help? many thanks

data    count   sum
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0   9   0
1
2
3
4
5
6
5
4   8   30
0
0
0
0
0
0   6   0
1
3
2
4
5
6   6   21
0
0
0
0   4   0

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you basically want to do a conditional count. You can do this with the `COUNTIF` function.

To find all the zeros:

`=COUNTIF(A2:A29, "0")`

The `COUNTIF` is a formula that counts cells if they fulfil a certain criteria. In my same formula, the cells in the range `A2:A29` are being counted IF they are `0`.

To find everything that is not zero:

`=COUNTIF(A2:A29, "<>0")`

The `<>` is the negation in Excel

I made a video on the `COUNTIF` function in case you want to learn more about it: https://youtu.be/I12dze35sJQ

Answer (score 0):

From your post I don't know exactly where are your data and where you expect results.
If your data are in column A and you expect results in rows where there are the last values in series you can use a dynamic formula in `D2`:

```
=LET(data,$A$3:$A$35,rd,ROW(data), 
res,FREQUENCY(IF(data,rd),IF(data,,rd))
 +FREQUENCY(IF(data,FALSE,rd),IF(data,rd,)), 
IF(res<>0,res,""))
```

To calculate subtotals you can use simple formula in `E3` which should be copied down

```
=IF(D3="","",SUM(A$3:A3)-SUM(E$2:E2))
```

If you prefer a dynamic formula you can enter in `E3`:

```
=IF(D$3:D$35<>"",SCAN(0,$A$3:$A$35,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=0,0,a+b))),"")
```

Data start from row 3, but formula in column D is in row 2. Or you get results 1 row below data.
[image: Count series]